# Check if 2 Hitboxes\Rectangles overlap in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have to hit boxes around my characters in a scrolling game, one around a zombie, and one around a ninja. They both follow the player and that is find, right now I need to find out how to check if they overlap, to check for collision.

I've read a few other stack overflow questions about this topic and the answers don't seem to be what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!!!

Here is a smaller version of my code:

```
class ninja(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, ninjawidth, ninjaheight):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ninjaheight = ninjaheight
        self.ninjawidth = ninjawidth
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 10, self.y + 10, self.ninjaheight - 10, self.ninjawidth - 10)
    def draw(self):
        mainninja.hitbox = (mainninja.x + 10, mainninja.y + 10, mainninja.ninjaheight - 15, mainninja.ninjawidth - 10)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), mainninja.hitbox,2) #here is the hitbox


class zombie(object):
    def __init__(self, zombiewidth, zombieheight):
        self.x = winwidth
        self.y = 391
        self.height = zombieheight
        self.width = zombiewidth
    def draw(self):
        self.hitbox = (zombie.x + 55, zombie.y + 35, zombie.width - 55, zombie.height - 45)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), zombie.hitbox, 2) #here is other hitbox


mainninja = ninja(60, 400, 192, 192)
zombie = zombie(192, 192)
```

I just want a code or function to put in main loop to check for collision between zombie and ninja hit boxes.

Comment: read about [pygame Rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). It has all the functionalities you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object for the `.hitbox` attributes.
Note you should use the `self` attribute in the methods of the class rather than the global namespace variables `mainninja` and `zombie`:

```py
class ninja(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, ninjawidth, ninjaheight):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.ninjaheight = ninjaheight
        self.ninjawidth = ninjawidth
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 10, self.y + 10, self.ninjaheight - 10, self.ninjawidth - 10)
    def draw(self):
        mainninja.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 10, self.y + 10, self.ninjaheight - 15, self.ninjawidth - 10)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), mainninja.hitbox,2) #here is the hitbox


class zombie(object):
    def __init__(self, zombiewidth, zombieheight):
        self.x = winwidth
        self.y = 391
        self.height = zombieheight
        self.width = zombiewidth
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 55, self.y + 35, self.width - 55, self.height - 45)
    def draw(self):
        self.hitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 55, self.y + 35, self.width - 55, self.height - 45)
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox, 2) #here is other hitbox

mainninja = ninja(60, 400, 192, 192)
zombie = zombie(192, 192)
```

Then you can use [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) to check for a collision:

```py
if mainninja.hitbox.colliderect(zombie.hitbox):
    # [...]
```

Comment: This seems exactly what i'm looking for, but when I run this i'm getting the error:                  AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'colliderect'                                                              Do you know why this is happening? Thanks for answer though.

Comment: @AndrewThePythonCoder Do you set the attribute `.hitbox` somewhere else in the program? It hast be always a `pygame.Rect` object!